# Can my chromecast SENDER application launch any activity on the receiver?

Tags: chromecast

specifically when using cast_api.addReceiverListener("YouTube"..... can I launch any activty besides youtube?

I don't want to write my own receiver application, what are the builtin receiver applications I can activate?

Is there a built in application to launch an arbitrary URL?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot launch any application that you want. Currently, your device needs to be whitelisted for an application and outside of your own app that you may have registered through the whitelisting process, there are very few apps that are "openly" available to you, such as YouTube.

At the moment, if you want to do anything "interesting", even playing back a simple media file, you need to write your own receiver.

Finally, there is no application to launch an arbitrary URL; you need to write your own receiver and app to achieve that (unless you mirror your Chromecast tab).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - what are the other options besides "Youtube" that are openly available?

Comment: I basically want  a way to show a business dashboard on my TV. This dashboard has a specific URL but I want to show it on 20 different screens with 20 different chromecast devices. Do I need to whitelist all of them?

Comment: While the SDK is in the preview mode, you need to whitelist all those 20 devices with an application/receiver that you need to write; there is no app that would do what you want. In addition, you need to "launch" that application on all those 20 devices; there is no option of "auto launch application X when rebooted" or so.

Comment: got it thanks! Any (rough) estimate on when the SDK will come out of preview?